# SQLSessionFactory in a Windows service throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

When I run my app from command line (java -jar forward.jar) everythings works ok, no exceptions thrown. However, when running the same app as a windows service I get NullPointerException.

> 19.06.2014 14:44:46.442 [DefaultListableBeanFactory] [AbstractBeanFactory.java] [DEBUG] [Thread-0  ] Ignoring bean creation
>   exception on FactoryBean type check:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'phoneNumberRepository' defined in URL
>   [jar:file:/C:/forward.jar!/com/forward/persistence/db/PhoneNumberRepository.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property
>   'sqlSessionFactory': : Error creating bean with name
>   'sqlSessionFactory' defined in URL
>   [jar:file:/C:/forward.jar!/mybatis-context.xml]: Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in URL
>   [jar:file:/C:/prem-forward.jar!/mybatis-context.xml]: Invocation of
>   init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

and then

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [com.forward.persistence.db.PhoneNumberRepository] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:988)
>   ~[spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
>   ~[spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
>   ~[spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
>   ~[spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]   ... 28 common frames
>   omitted

Hier ist my myBatis-context.xml definition:

```
<import resource="classpath*:datasource-context.xml"/>

<mybatis:scan base-package="com.forward.persistence.db" />

<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="com.forward.model"/> <!-- Register the short names of beans as aliases -->
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:mybatis-config.xml"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- scan for mappers and let them be autowired -->
<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="com.forward.persistence.db" />
</bean>
```

UPDATE: The definition of PhoneNumberRepository.xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<resultMap type="com.forward.model.PhoneNumber" id="phoneMap">
    <result column="number" property="number"/>
    <result column="partition" property="partition"/>
</resultMap>

<select id="findAll"  resultMap="phoneMap">
    SELECT *
    FROM PhoneNumber
    ORDER BY number;
</select>
```

MyBatis mapps the interphace PhoneNumberRepository to this .xml file to create the bean.

Comment: Please show the definition of `com.forward.persistence.db.PhoneNumberRepository`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with Java service being different on the deploying machine and local machine where the project was compiled.